# c - errors in linux kernel linked list

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linked-list, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm using the linux kernel linked list in order to create a linked list of message slots that are distinguished using a minor number, each slot has a linked list of channels that are distingushed using a channel ID.
I used linux/list.h linked list.

```
    struct msgSlot {
    int minor;
    struct channel* channels; //Linked list for channels
    struct list_head list; //Linked list for msg slots
};

struct channel {
    char* msg;
    int id;
    struct list_head list;
};

//static struct msgSlot msgSlotsList;
//LIST_HEAD_INIT(&msgSlotsList.list);
LIST_HEAD(msgSlotsList);

static int numOfSlots = 0;


// The message the device will give when asked
static char the_message[BUF_LEN];

//================== DEVICE FUNCTIONS ===========================
static int device_open(struct inode* inode, struct file* file) {
    unsigned long flags; // for spinlock
    printk("Invoking device_open(%p)\n", file);

    int fileExists = 0; //Used as a flag to check whether the file exists or not
    struct msgSlot *tmp;
    list_for_each_entry(tmp, &msgSlotsList.list, list)
    {
        if (tmp->minor == iminor(inode)) {
            fileExists = 1;
            break; //No need to keep looking
        }

    }

    if (fileExists == 0) { //Need to open a new file
        struct msgSlot *slot = kmalloc(sizeof(struct msgSlot), GFP_KERNEL); //Create msg slot
        slot->minor = iminor(inode);
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&slot->list);
        list_add(&slot->list, &msgSlotsList.list); //Add to list
        //struct channel *channels = kmalloc(sizeof(struct channel), GFP_KERNEL);
        //LIST_HEAD_INIT(&channels->list);
        LIST_HEAD(channels);
        slot->channels = channels;

    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile my code I get the following errors:

```
    message_slot.c:53:40: error: ‘struct list_head’ has no member named ‘list’
  list_for_each_entry(tmp, &msgSlotsList.list, list)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the complete code so that it can be verified by compiling on machine?

Comment: `LIST_HEAD(msgSlotsList);` you have not indicated the type of the list. LIST_HEAD() takes two arguments you have passed only one argument.

Comment: @Gaurav [does it](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ace52288edf0cb5e7a52b681f057f86224c49c27/include/linux/list.h#L23)?

Comment: @tgregory Sorry! My bad, I was referring to macro defined in `sys/queue.h`

Comment: Macro `list_for_each_entry` accepts "the head for your list" as the second argument. Just pass `&msgSlotsList` to the macro. Not sure what do you mean by passing `&msgSlotsList.list` instead.

Comment: After you fix your current issue, start learning what locking means and why it's needed.